# Smooth Swipe With ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Using a ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback I was able to implement left and right swiping on RecyclerView rows, however the default implementation abruptly removes list items. How could I reduce the speed of these removals?

Answer (score 0):

you can use these library for your work
[https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout](https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayouthttp://)

https://github.com/TR4Android/Swipeable-RecyclerView

Answer (score 0):

```
        val simpleCallbackItemTouchHelper = object :
                ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
                    0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT or
                        ItemTouchHelper.LEFT
                ) {     
        override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                           viewHolder:RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                           target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
                return true
            }

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {}

        override fun onChildDraw(
            c: Canvas,
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            dX: Float,
            dY: Float,
            actionState: Int,
            isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
        ) {}
    }

    simpleCallbackItemTouchHelper.getSwipeEscapeVelocity(0.25f)
    val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallbackItemTouchHelper)
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(view)
```

I added this in my bindingAdapter and gave a **swipeEscapeVelocity** for the **simpleCallbackItemTouchHelper** as you see in the above code .
 It's working for me.
Please try this and respond.